# 2 simple statistics questions regarding probability and means.

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation, sampling, means

1. Fire alarms go off in the engineering building an average of 13 times per year. Find the probability of more than one fire alarm going off in the month of December.

For this one, I am uncertain on what equation to use, as very little information is provided.

2. The weight of a male is a random variable with mean = 185 lbs and standard deviation = 20lbs. A military airplane holds 100 random males on each flight. The total weight of these men is 100 times the average male s weight and the SD of the total weight is 100 times the SD of the average male s weight. Over a large number of flights, what is the estimated total weight of 100 men in an airplane?

For this one, I think I am clearly under thinking it. There must be something more complicated to do than just multiplying by 100, yes?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.   Please restrict to one question per post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q2 first: The profuse data is just to bamboozle you, your thinking is right.

Q1: In this data sparse problems, you can use the Poisson distribution.  Note that $\lambda$ will be $\dfrac{13}{12}$

Comment: You're welcome ! ☺